# Eclipse - warn bad indentation in html files

Tags: html, eclipse, indentation

I couldnt find a configuration to warn for bad indentation in html files in eclipse. Did i miss something or is there a plugin i can use?

example:

```
<body>  
<div> <!--- warn --->
    <p></p>
</div>
</body>
```

I'm writing code in Javascript, python and html and i'm looking for a consistent way of programming cause i will share my code with a friend.

Comment: The comment in your HTML example looks wrong. Did you mean to write it as `<!-- warn -->` instead of `<!--- warn ---!>`?

Comment: the comment doesnt care...i only wanted to show where i want to have a warnning mark

Answer (score 0):

i don't know a plugin that warns when indentation in eclipse is bad but with auto-code-format you shouldn't need one. (maybe that's the reason why there is none)

The best way would be to just share a code formatter (preferences -> search for "formatter") to your team/friend and tell them to activate the "Automatically format code on save"-option (preferences -> Save Actions) -> eclipse will automatically format the code according to your formatter, so no indentation problems will occur.
Even without a customized formatter this way will clean your code very well.

Comment: there is no formatter for html files :/ do i have to use the formatter in pydev section?

Comment: you are right - eclipse does not offer a formatter for html. you can change html formatting via window -> preferences -> web -> HTML files -> Editor. for python you can use Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Style -> Code Formatter